# xcopy not working on user profiles

Tags: batch-file, backup, user-profile

I came across this batch script before, that allows me to copy files into another directory. Nice, easy, one click backup.

I've used it for a while one one specific, important directory, now I'm trying to copy all the user profiles, so the folder `C:\Users` and all of its sub folders. And it kind of works, but stops what seems partway through...

I only get the app data folder of my current user copied, but no desktop, no documents, no nothing. Also, while it completely copied all of the data of my first user, my last user is not copied at all.

```
@echo off
:: variables
set drive=E:\BACKUP_user_profiles
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

echo ### Backing up user profiles...
%backupcmd% "C:\Users" "%drive%"

echo Backup Complete!
```

Could this script be interupted by a certain file in my App data directory?
It worked fine for the current user on another computer, so it doesn't seem to be a "files are in use" issue...

Any ideas?

Comment: Your running the script as administrator?

Comment: Yes and I get the same result either way

Comment: try with `robocopy "C:\Users" "%drive%" *.*` (robocopy /? for switches) and see if you get a more illuminating error (its superior to xcopy anyway)

Comment: @olli There are locked files in the `c:\users` tree that can't be copied without using volume shadow copy techniques - so you can't get a complete backup.  Robocopy will not be able to copy them either, and will try again and again by default.